# Strange reflection behavior in php Laravel 4

Tags: php, reflection, laravel-4

This seems like a fairly simple reflection problem, yet I can't figure it our. I use Laravel 4.2 on Debian with PHP 5.6.6-1.

Basicly what happens is that I want to spawn a new object from a class in a Laravel QueueHandler like so:

```
$className = 'MyClass';
$myobject = new $className ();
```

and this doesn't work. I tried everything I can possibly think of and have no clue where to look. This code doesn;t work while it should:

```
<?php
use Pronamic\Twinfield\Secure\Config;
use Pronamic\Twinfield\Customer\CustomerFactory;

class TwinfieldQueueHandler {
  private $twinfieldConfig = null;
```

...

```
try {
  $twinfieldFactoryClass = 'CustomerFactory';

  //returns 0
  echo strcmp('CustomerFactory', $twinfieldFactoryClass);

  //works
  $test0 = new CustomerFactory ($this->twinfieldConfig);

  //throws an exeption with message:  "Class CustomerFactory does not exist"
  $r = new ReflectionClass($twinfieldFactoryClass);
  $test1 = $r->newInstanceArgs($this->twinfieldConfig);

  //gives error PHP Fatal error:  Class 'CustomerFactory' not found in {file} on line {line}
  $test2 = new $twinfieldFactoryClass ($this->twinfieldConfig);

} catch (Exception $e) {
  Log::error($e->getMessage());
}
```

Has anyone got any pointers on where to look and how to debug this?

Comment: It's a stretch but the only thing I've been able to think of is something to do with the reflection/variable method not picking up namespaces properly. Perhaps try defining the class using the full explicit namespace? i.e. `$twinfieldFactoryClass = '\Pronamic\Twinfield\Customer\CustomerFactory';`. Long shot though..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ReflectionClass` will ignore your current namespace and `use` statements completely. You have to specify the fully qualified name of the class:

```
$r = new ReflectionClass('Pronamic\Twinfield\Customer\CustomerFactory');
```

As a user points out on [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/class.reflectionclass.php#89926):

> To reflect on a namespaced class in PHP 5.3, you must always specify the fully qualified name of the class - even if you've aliased the containing namespace using a "use" statement.

---

Note that you could work around this by passing an object:

```
$test0 = new CustomerFactory ($this->twinfieldConfig);

$r = new ReflectionClass($test0);
```